# How to smooth the DTM?

Tags: qgis, dem, smoothing

I had a point file of an area around 70 km^2 collected through field survey using Auto Level. The survey was carried out in the lines 25 m apart. I converted the readings from auto level into point shapefile and then converted the point shapefile into DTM using Grid- IDW (nearest neighbour selection) tool with search radius of 25 m in QGIS. However, in the DTM prepared through GIS has lot of discontinuity in form of strips at the distance of 25 m. I wish to smoothen these strips. Can you suggest the reasons?[image]

Comment: Were the data acquired in parallel lines? Seismic?

Answer (score 3):

Change the resampling option for the rendering.

- Here is an example with default display:

[image]

The blocky nature is due to the way hillshades are sampled within cells.

The **Layer Styling** panel has **Resampling** options. Change *Nearest Neighbour* to *Bilinear* or *Cubic*. This can be done when zoomed in or out or both:

[image]

The result is a smoother raster:

[image]

Comment: This didn't help.

Comment: Did you set it for both zoomed in and zoomed out?